# "be driven by something"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Spending on cosmetic surgery in UK  has risen by more than a third,
>   driven by the rising number of businesspeople who are going under the
>   knife to help them climb the career ladder.

What does the "driven by" in this sentence mean?

Answer (score 4):

In this case, **driven** what is *driving* or *causing* the rising spend in cosmetic surgery.

> Housing prices are rising, **driven** by lower interest rates.
>   *lower interest rates (financing) is causing people to buy houses*

Answer (score 1):

> Driven

Providing the power to keep a machine working, or to make something happen.

For example:

> - The new ships, propelled by gas turbines, require less maintenance
>     than older, **steam-driven** ones.
> - The fact remains that there are some public services that cannot be
>     entirely **market-driven** (= controlled by economic forces).

[Source : Driven](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/driven)

Comment: The question asked meaning in the provided context. How is your answer related to it?